# $X$ is martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Let be $B$ and $D$ independent Brownian motion. Let be $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ constant. Define $$M_t = \alpha (\int_0^t B_s dD_s + \int_0^t D_s dB_s)$$ and $$N_t = \frac{\alpha^2}{2} \int_0^t (B_s^2 + D_s^2)ds$$

Let be $X_t = cos(M_t)e^{N_t}$.

First i need to prove that $X_t$ is local martingale. I did it. But now i need to explain that $X_t$ is also martingale.

How can i prove it?

Comment: "Assume that [...] for every $\beta>0$ is $E\exp(\beta \max_{0 \leq s \leq t} B_s^2)<\infty$" ... well, unfortunatly this assumption is wrong. The expectation is only finite for $\beta$ small enough

Comment: ok if assumption is true, how can i prove that $X_t$ is martingale?

Comment: Well, but your "assumption" is wrong. If you start with a wrong assumption, you can essentially prove everything. If $0=1$, then $(X_t)_t$ is a martingale and the earth is a disc... yeah, so what?

Comment: yeah i get it, this exercise has wrong assumption. So let's forget about this and take another way to prove that $X$ is martingale. Can i take stopping time $T = inf \{ t \geq 0; \int_0^t (B_s^2 + D_s^2)ds > 1 \}$ and then with optional stopping theorem prove that $X$ is martingale?

Comment: I believe that the assertion of your problem is wrong, more precisely, I doubt that $X_t$ is integrable. (And no, using stopping techniques isn't much good here, because this will only prove that $X$ is a local martingale... which you already did.)

Comment: So that's why i cannot get a solution, thank you